# non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ after Cohen forcing over a model where Choice fails

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is it possible that (under reasonable assumptions about $V$) that there exists an inner model $W\subset V$ such that $W\supset \mathbb{R}$, there exists an uncountable cardinal $\lambda$ with $W\models \lambda\rightarrow (\omega_1)^\omega_2$ (choice fails in $W$!) and $W^{Add(\omega,\lambda)}\models$ there exists a non-principle ultrafilter on $\omega$? In fact, I'm not even sure if the infinite exponent partition relation is compatible with the fact that there exists a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$. (I take choice for granted most of the time so this might reflect my ignorance.)

Comment: I need a refreshment on partition notation.

Comment: Sure $\lambda \to (\omega_1)^\omega_2$ means for any $f: [\lambda]^\omega \to 2$ there exists $A \in [\lambda]^{\omega_1}$ such that $f''[A]^\omega$ is constant.

Comment: So, assume large cardinals, and $L(\Bbb R)$ is your $W$, with $\lambda=\omega_1$. So far all the conditions hold, right? So essentially, we want to know if there is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ after adding $\omega_1$ Cohen reals?

Comment: yeah but I'm also afraid that if AD is true, there will be no non-principle ultrafilter on $\omega$ in the ground. I doubt if Cohen forcing adds it. I had something like $L(\mathbb{R})[U]$ in mind. But again I don't know how to show/refute it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be wary about all that.